# UIScrollView with parallax like Airbnb

Tags: ios

I'm trying to create a scroll view like the one used in the airbnb app.

At start the view display the image and under the image there is many subviews with info.
when scrolling the image start to shrink in a parallax way till it's gone.

Any ideas how to implement it ? I prefer to understand how it's done rater then using some github control

Comment: I don't have AirBnB, a video/image explaining the effect could be useful. But I think that if you look in CocoaControls for `tableView` you may find your effect, or at least a kind of effect similar that you'll have to modify or be inspired with..